# How to get skype downloaded images, videos, documents, audios to android app

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, skype, android-file, android-fileprovider

I want to fetch all the downloaded images, videos, documents, audios and display in to my app.
I don't want any other images, videos, documents, audios except for skype downloaded files.
I have tried to fetch files using folder name but only images, videos are saving inside "0/Photos/Skype/"
remaining documents are storing inside the "0/Downloads"
I can fetch download folder also but I don't want any other download files except for the Skype files.

Is it possible to get skype file or not?

I want to fetch skype downloaded files and display into my app.

Comment: The "folder names" you use only exist when accessing the device via MTP. Use adb to see the real file-system names and paths. But since Android 111 apps you have to use ScopedStorage API of Android to access files in those directories.

Comment: How do these Skype file names in Download folder look like? You can then just check for the right file names.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.